# Delete lines comes after a specific line in Shell

Tags: shell, design-patterns, lines

I'm trying to delete all lines comes after a specific pattern in files.

I have many files, which all have the same structure :

Example:

file1

line 1
...
line x "here there is a specific pattern"
...
EOF

...
...

file n

line 1
...
line x "here there is a specific pattern"
...
EOF

I tried to get a simple solution, but since I have many files, I proceed with a long way :p

The pattern appears one time in each file.

So, I got all lines number which contains this pattern, and save in one file.

this is my code :

```
count=$(ls -f path_to_folder/*.txt | wc -l)
echo "Number of txt file : $count"
###


    for ((i=1;i < $count+1 ;i++))

    {

    vt=$(grep -n PATTERN $i.txt | cut -d : -f 1)
    echo $vt >> PATTERN_line.txt

    }
```

Every line in PATTERN_line.txt contains the line number, in each file, where the pattern exists.

Now, I'm trying to use those number to delete all line comes after Pattern to the file end.
which mean, I need to keep the file, from the head to patten line included.

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use below sed command, also read my comments in the script to understand how will it work:-

```
#list all the files in a temporary file
cd /path_to_folder/
ls -1 *.txt > list_of_files.txt

#now read each file from the temp file
while read file
do
    #redirect the output to a temporary file
    sed -n '/here there is a specific pattern/q;p' "$file" > temp.txt
    #sed -n '/here there is a specific pattern/p' "$file" >> temp.txt
    #uncomment the above line if your want to including the line match as well
    mv temp.txt "$file"
    #change the file name
done < list_of_files.txt
rm -rf list_of_files.txt
```